# Back up database without making it to read-only

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-backups

I am taking back up of a database which is expected to take 2 Hours. I am new to this backup process and trying to learn. I have following doubts:

1. What if someone tries to insert some record in between?
2. Have I done anything wrong by not making the database read-only before taking the backup?

Comment: Which `DBMS` are you using?

Comment: [This article](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/more-on-how-much-transaction-log-a-full-backup-includes/) has a timeline that explains it quite nicely.

Comment: What type of backup are you doing?  A SQL Server Full Backup will handle this.

Comment: I am doing Full backup.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the backup procedure, a recovery process will take place on the backed up database, syncing it with a snapshot of your database which had the new records added in. So by the end of the backup your database will be fully up to date, including any records inserted/updated while the backup took place.